# Loading Json object into datatable (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I want to use a JSON object to build a datatable, but I receive the following error:

[image]

after that,  the browser shows :

[image]

I was trying by hours everthing that the url in the warning message says.. but i didnt figure out.

The JSON object is retrieved by a servlet named MyJson. This JSon has the following appareance.

```
{
    "data":[
        ["NAME: Name1","DIRECTION: Salida","CHARGED: 15","AFFORDED: 15"],
        ["NAME: Name2","DIRECTION: Salida","CHARGED: 4","AFFORDED: 4"],
        ["NAME: Name3","DIRECTION: Entrada","CHARGED: 4","AFFORDED: 4"],
        ["NAME: Name4","DIRECTION: Salida","CHARGED: 1","AFFORDED: 0"],
        ["NAME: Name5","DIRECTION: Entrada","CHARGED: 15","AFFORDED: 15"],
        ["NAME: Name6","DIRECTION: Entrada","CHARGED: 10","AFFORDED: 10"],
        ["NAME: Name7","DIRECTION: Entrada","CHARGED: 15","AFFORDED: 15"],
        ["NAME: Name8","DIRECTION: Entrada","CHARGED: 3","AFFORDED: 3"],
        ["NAME: Name9","DIRECTION: Entrada","CHARGED: 15","AFFORDED: 15"]
    ]
}
```

And this is my javascript

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {    
    var tableEntityList = $('#testable').DataTable({        
        "processing": true,
        "scrollY":"500px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":false,
        "serverSide":true,
        "ajax":"./MyJson",
        "columns": [
            { "data":'NAME' },
            { "data":'DIRECTION' },
            { "data":'CHARGED' },
            { "data":'AFFORDED' }   
        ]
    });
})
</script>

<body>

<table class="display responsive nowrap" id="testable" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>DIRECTION</th>
<th>CHARGED</th>
<th>AFFORDED</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Can you tell me what am i doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to process your data before passing it to DataTables and you can do this within [`dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc). Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/wz1qy3qg/):

```
let jsonData = {
    "data": [
        ["NAME: Name1", "DIRECTION: Salida", "CHARGED: 15", "AFFORDED: 15"],
        ["NAME: Name2", "DIRECTION: Salida", "CHARGED: 4", "AFFORDED: 4"],
        ["NAME: Name3", "DIRECTION: Entrada", "CHARGED: 4", "AFFORDED: 4"],
        ["NAME: Name4", "DIRECTION: Salida", "CHARGED: 1", "AFFORDED: 0"],
        ["NAME: Name5", "DIRECTION: Entrada", "CHARGED: 15", "AFFORDED: 15"],
        ["NAME: Name6", "DIRECTION: Entrada", "CHARGED: 10", "AFFORDED: 10"],
        ["NAME: Name7", "DIRECTION: Entrada", "CHARGED: 15", "AFFORDED: 15"],
        ["NAME: Name8", "DIRECTION: Entrada", "CHARGED: 3", "AFFORDED: 3"],
        ["NAME: Name9", "DIRECTION: Entrada", "CHARGED: 15", "AFFORDED: 15"]
    ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var tableEntityList = $('#testable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "scrollY": "500px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging": false,
        "ajax": {
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: {
                json: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
            },
            dataSrc: function(json) {
                var properData = [];
                $.each(json.data, function(k, v) {
                    var returnObject = {};
                    $.each(v, function(a, b) {
                        var elArr = b.split(":");
                        returnObject[elArr[0].trim()] = elArr[1].trim()
                    });
                    properData.push(returnObject)
                });
                return properData;
            }
        },
        "columns": [{
            "data": 'NAME'
        }, {
            "data": 'DIRECTION'
        }, {
            "data": 'CHARGED'
        }, {
            "data": 'AFFORDED'
        }]
    });
});
```

Please note though that `serverSide` will not work!

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data), it means your JSON array should already have fields mapped with respective field name `NAME`,`DIRECTION`, `CHARGED` and `AFFORDED` like this :

```
var dataSet = [
    { "NAME": "Name1", "DIRECTION": "Salida",  "CHARGED": 15, "AFFORDED": 15 },
    { "NAME": "Name2", "DIRECTION": "Salida",  "CHARGED": 4,  "AFFORDED": 4 },
    { "NAME": "Name3", "DIRECTION": "Entrada", "CHARGED": 4,  "AFFORDED": 4 },
    { "NAME": "Name4", "DIRECTION": "Salida",  "CHARGED": 1,  "AFFORDED": 0 },
    { "NAME": "Name5", "DIRECTION": "Entrada", "CHARGED": 15, "AFFORDED": 15 },
    { "NAME": "Name6", "DIRECTION": "Entrada", "CHARGED": 10, "AFFORDED": 10 },
    { "NAME": "Name7", "DIRECTION": "Entrada", "CHARGED": 15, "AFFORDED": 15 },
    { "NAME": "Name8", "DIRECTION": "Entrada", "CHARGED": 3,  "AFFORDED": 3 },
    { "NAME": "Name9", "DIRECTION": "Entrada", "CHARGED": 15, "AFFORDED": 15}
];
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmartel/tqz0t206/1/)

In your case you want to have only data without field name since you are using embedded array, you should have something like :

```
var dataSet = [
    ["Name1", "Salida",  "15", "15"],
    ["Name2", "Salida",  "4",  "4"],
    ["Name3", "Entrada", "4",  "4"],
    ["Name4", "Salida",  "1",  "0"],
    ["Name5", "Entrada", "15", "15"],
    ["Name6", "Entrada", "10", "10"],
    ["Name7", "Entrada", "15", "15"],
    ["Name8", "Entrada", "3",  "3"],
    ["Name9", "Entrada", "15", "15"]
];
```

You can change `columns.data` to `column.title` to set the data title directly for each array item index. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmartel/tqz0t206/2/)

As you have included field name in your data. The best is to modify your JSON input source to return something directly usable. If you can't doing it, you can modify the data you receive and reorganize it by removing the embedded field name and then initialize datatables with the new modified input.

Answer (score 0):

annoyingmouse approach solved my problem.

My final call is:

```
    var tableEntityList = $('#testable').DataTable({        
        "processing": true,
        "scrollY":"500px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":false,
        "serverSide":true,
        "ajax":{
            url:"./MyJson",
            dataSrc: function(json) {
                var properData = [];
                $.each(json.data, function(k, v) {
                    var returnObject = {};
                    $.each(v, function(a, b) {
                        var elArr = b.split(":");
                        returnObject[elArr[0].trim()] = elArr[1].trim()
                    });
                    properData.push(returnObject)
                });
                return properData;
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data":'NAME' },
            { "data":'DIRECTION' },
            { "data":'CHARGED' },
            { "data":'AFFORDED' }   
        ]   
    });
```